# Removing the only element of a vector during iteration?

Tags: c++, c++98

I'm a tad confused about iterators. I'd like to remove a vector member which happens to have a certain value, even if it is the only element in the vector.

I have a vector of a class. What I'd like to do is when one of class member's variables, such as `width`, is of a certain value this class instance will be removed permanently from the vector. Let's assume that class is made out of just a constructor, taking in `width` and `height`, both public variables, and a destructor as its public functions.

```
vector<Rectangle> vect1;

Rectangle memVar1(3, 5);
Rectangle memVar2(6, 10);

vect1.push_back(memVar1);
vect1.push_back(memVar2);
```

So it will iterate through all members of the vector, searching if any height is 5.

```
for(std::vector<myClass>::iterator it = vect1.begin(); it != vect1.end(); ++it) {
    if (it->height == 5) {
    //delete the element from the vector, and so memVar2 will be the only element and it will be in slot 0 of the vector now.
    it = vect1.erase(it);
    } 
}
```

And that works as expected, the problem arises if there is just one element in the vector, which happens to have the unwanted height of 5. I'd like to remove the element from vector, but then also safely exit the iteration. In the instance above, I could put in a `break` after setting it to vect1.erase(it) but this wouldn't work if my erase was inside a switch inside of the iteration loop, for example, and so I would need a conditional variable to exit from there when it leaves the switch statement.

So I was wondering if there is a way to do it which doesn't require me to use `break`, to prevent having clutter code if I'm erasing inside a switch statement?

Comment: use the erase remove idiom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Comment: @Swordfish I forgot to mention _instead of incrementing it in the loop header_.

Comment: @molbdnilo: That's basically the answer - you skip over an element, which isn't there when the deleting the last (or only) element of a vector.

Comment: you already accepted my answer, though i felt my explanation was not really accurate. See edit of the answer for the better explanation of whats wrong in your code

Comment: Note that you will get a complexity O(n^2) if too many elements need to be removed. You will get a O(n) complexity by simply creating a new vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When deleteing elements in a loop you have to consider that when you delete element at index `i` then the next element is at index `i` not at index `i+1`. Also erasing an element in a vector invalidates all iterators at and after the position you erased (actually you already take this into account). Hence the loop should look something like:

```
for(auto it = vect1.begin(); it != vect1.end(); /* no increment here */) {
    if (it->height == 5) {
        it = vect1.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

PS: only after writing the answer I realized that my explanation is bogus. The correct explanation is that `erase` does already return an iterator to the element after the one you erased, so you shouldnt increment it.